# $\mathbb R$ as continuum many of pairwise disjoint of Bernstein sets

Tags: set-theory, transfinite-recursion, transfinite-induction

The set $B\subset\mathbb R$ is called Bernstein set if neither $B$ nor $\mathbb R\setminus B$ contains any perfect sets.

**Theorem**: $\mathbb R$ can be written as continuum many of pairwise disjoint Bernstein sets.

**Proof**:  Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a family of all perfect subsets of $\mathbb R$. Then  $|\mathcal{P}\times\mathbb R|=\mathfrak c , $ so we can choose an enumeration $\{\langle P_\xi,y_\xi\rangle\colon\xi<\mathfrak c\}$ of $\mathcal{P} \times \mathbb R.$
We will construct, by induction on $\xi<\mathfrak c,$ a
sequence $\{x_\xi\colon \xi<\mathfrak c\}$ such that

$$x_\xi\in P_\xi\setminus\{x_\zeta\colon \zeta<\xi\}$$

Since each $x_\lambda\neq x_\xi$ for all $\lambda<\xi<\mathfrak c$, we can define $f$ on $\{x_\xi\colon \xi<\mathfrak c\}$ such that $f(x_\xi)=y_\xi$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise.

**Claim** : $f^{-1}(r)$ is Bernstein set for each $r\in\mathbb R.$

Indeed, for each $r\in\mathbb R$ and $P\in\mathcal P$ there is an $\xi<\mathfrak c$ such that $\langle r,P\rangle = \langle r_\xi, P_\xi \rangle$,  then $x_\xi\in f^{-1}(r_\xi)\cap P_\xi=f^{-1}(r) \cap P\neq \emptyset.$  Also the same true for the complement for $f^{-1}(r)$ (as $f^{-1}(t)$ where $t\neq r$).  Then $f^{-1} (r)$ is Bernstein for all $r\in\mathbb R$. It is clear that $$ \mathbb R=\bigcup_{r\in\mathbb R} f^{-1} (r)$$ as we need.

I have no probelm with this proof at all. My question is Can we have the same result without  define function like that? I mean just start to construct the by transfinite induction. I would love to see completely different approache to get the same result. I am hoping for theos who have deeply understanding for transfinite induction to share their proofs.

Comment: Proper notation is $\langle P_\xi,y_\xi\rangle,$ not $< P_\xi,y_\xi>.$ I edited accordingly.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, Thank you for fixing

Answer (score 6):

First, and least important, your construction is by **recursion**, not by induction: induction is a proof technique.

Next, the argument doesn’t really use the function $f$ at all: you could just as well define your Bernstein sets by letting $B_r=\{x_\xi:y_\xi=r\}$ for each $r\in\Bbb R$.

Finally, your construction does not ensure that the union of your Bernstein sets is all of $\Bbb R$; it could, for instance, be $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ if you happened to choose irrational numbers for all of your points $x_\xi$. If you want them to be a partition of $\Bbb R$, you have to be a bit more careful in your recursion.

Enumerate $\Bbb R=\{r_\xi:\xi<\mathfrak{c}\}$. At stage $\eta$, when you’ve already chosen $x_\xi$ for all $\xi<\eta$, let $\mu=\min\big\{\zeta<\mathfrak{c}:r_\zeta\in P_\eta\setminus\{x_\xi:\xi<\eta\}\big\}$, and let $x_\eta=r_\mu$. This is just your construction with a little extra care taken in choosing **which** point of $P_\eta\setminus\{x_\xi:\xi<\eta\}$ to use as $x_\eta$, so it does give you pairwise disjoint Bernstein sets $B_r=\{x_\xi:y_\xi=r\}$ for $r\in\Bbb R$.

Suppose that $\Bbb R\setminus\bigcup_{r\in\Bbb R}B_r\ne\varnothing$, let $r_\nu\in\Bbb R\setminus\bigcup_{r\in\Bbb R}B_r$ and let $X=\{\xi<\mathfrak{c}:r_\nu\in P_\xi\}$; then $|X|=\mathfrak{c}$, and $x_\xi\in P_\xi$ for each $\xi\in X$. For each $\xi\in X$ there is a $\mu(\xi)<\mathfrak{c}$ such that $x_\xi=r_{\mu(\xi)}$, and the points $x_\xi$ are distinct, so the map $\mu$ is injective. Let $M=\{\mu(\xi):\xi\in X\}$; $|M|=\mathfrak{c}$, so we can let $\theta=\min\{\mu\in M:\nu\le\mu\}$. Note that $\theta=\mu(\eta)$ for some $\eta\in X$, and $x_\eta=r_\theta$.

By hypothesis $r_\nu\notin\bigcup_{r\in\Bbb R}B_r$, so there is no $\xi<\mathfrak{c}$ such that $x_\xi=r_\nu$, and therefore $\theta>\nu$. But this is impossible: $r_\nu\in P_\eta\setminus\{x_\xi:\xi<\eta\}$, and $\nu<\theta$, so at stage $\eta$, when we chose $x_\eta$, $\theta$ was not the least element of $\big\{\zeta<\mathfrak{c}:r_\zeta\in P_\eta\setminus\{x_\xi:\xi<\eta\}\big\}$, and we did not set $x_\eta=r_\theta$.

**Added:** Here are a few links to answers of mine containing constructions by transfinite recursion, and one to an old paper of mine that does so; I’ve arranged them very roughly in ascending order of complexity. [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103551/second-category-but-not-locally-residual/103642#103642), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66132/chain-of-closed-subsets-in-separable-metric-space/66919#66919), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3672195/nowhere-dense-sets-and-metric-space/3672280#3672280), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169714/whats-application-of-bernstein-set/169718#169718), [5](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345950/is-there-an-ad-family-mathcal-q-of-size-aleph-1-which-is-not-a-luzin-gap/345968#345968), [6](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1762522/characterize-those-functions-which-maps-open-interval-to-open-intervals/1763980#1763980), [7](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1569130/every-topological-space-can-be-realized-as-the-quotient-of-some-hausdorff-space/1569463#1569463), [8](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290661/incomparable-subsets-of-real-numbers-with-usual-order-relation/290825#290825), [9](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409742/cantors-theorem-with-posets/1409790#1409790), [10](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2073427/must-every-subset-of-mathbb-r-contain-2-homeomorphic-distinct-open-sets/2086220#2086220), [11](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1975-053-01/S0002-9939-1975-0377824-8/S0002-9939-1975-0377824-8.pdf) [PDF; see **Theorem** $\bf{5}$].

Comment: @Brain You are right. Once again, Could you say by words, how can I understand the definition. $B_r=\{x_\xi\colon y_\xi=r\}  I do not know why I have trouble with this definition. It seems useful since it uses for many different construction

Comment: @00GB: Recall that $\{\langle P_\xi,y_\xi\rangle:\xi<\mathfrak{c}\}$ is an enumeration of $\mathscr{P}\times\Bbb R$. If $r\in\Bbb R$, each of the pairs $\langle P,r\rangle$ for $P\in\mathscr{P}$ is a different $\langle P_\xi,y_\xi\rangle$. That is, there are $\mathfrak{c}$ different ordinals $\xi$ such that $y_\xi=r$, and if $X$ is the set of those ordinals, then $\{P_\xi:\xi\in X\}=\mathscr{P}$, because $r$ gets paired with every perfect set. I’m just setting $B_r=\{x_\xi:\xi\in X\}$: for any perfect $P$ there is a $\xi\in X$ such that $P=P_\xi$, and $x_\xi\in B_r\cap P_\xi$.

Comment: @Brain, that's help. If you know could you refer me the reference ( book , notes, etc) that has more example about  construction is by recursion. This would be great

Comment: @00GB: I originally learned to carry out such constructions partly be seeing a few in lectures but mostly by encountering them in papers, so I’m not sure that I can easily come up with a source or two containing a useful number of different examples, but I’ll give it some thought; I might be able to offer a couple of suggestions.

Comment: Brian  Please do so this would be great. I was trying but I could not find

Comment: @00GB: I’ve added some links to old answers of mine that contain constructions by transfinite recursion; some are very simple, and a couple are fairly complicated.

Comment: We  can construct a pair-wise disjoint $F=\{F_x: x<c\}$ where $|F|=c$ and each $F_x$ intersects  every perfect set. Consider $G=\{G_x: x< c\}$ where $G_x=F_x$ for $x\ne 0$ and $G_0=F_0\cup (\Bbb R \setminus \cup F).$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott,Thank you very much

Comment: @00GB: You’re very welcome. I hope that they help.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, Yes, it does

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I believe the same will be working if we need to show that each Bernstein set can be written as a continuum of many pairwise disjoint Bernstein sets. Or, there is an easy way to show that

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, the same can be used if we need to show that every Bernstein set can be partitioned into $\mathfrak c$-many Bernstein sets, Is that right? Or there is another to see that